# Custom gui control

Tags: android, xml

i have to make a gui control which have some input boxes which will be like this
![enter image description here][1]
and at the boottom of that their will be some button when u click a button value of button will be displayed in the input box. So my question is that can some suggest me how acheive that input box style. Any suggestion would be greatly help for me. I am thinking of styling a button like these boxes and then call method of settext to display text. But there is also one more challange which is that at some state i have to show double value at boxes like this

![enter image description here][2]
So please suggest me any idea to acheive that

Comment: You can create xml file for the same and apply them to on your `EditText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use styles. For this create a XML file in your drawable folder. In this file use Shape with corner attribute. The code for following is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<corners android:radius="25dp" />
```

Use this code as backgraund of your button[image]

Comment: This is not exactly the solution but you are the one who show me the way. Now i have achieved, what i wanted. So that is why i am marking your post as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Follow this android developer link and you may get better idea how to go for it.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html